# image onclick action to navigate to another jsp page using JSP

Tags: image, jsp

This is the code I have written to navigate to another jsp page onclicking the image. But, I didn't get the output. Please help me out.

```
<td align="center"  >
       <img src="image.jsp?imgid=<%=rs.getInt(1)%>" width="100" height="100" **onclick="ModelList.jsp"** >
```

Comment: why do u write ** before onclick ??? and after

Comment: no thats actually I tried to highlight that.. by mistake the outcome was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Onclick is an event which expects an event handler (e.g a javascript function) to handle the even. so you can do something like this

```
onclick="window.href.location = ModelList.jsp"
```

Answer (score 0):

the below alteration will work ..

```
 <a href="ModelList.jsp"> <img src="image.jsp?imgid=<%=rs.getInt(1)%>" width="100" height="100"  ></a>
```